# Can't load angular html template in IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to load a template using ng-include and a path to the html file containing my template. This works in Chrome and Firefox but for some reason doesn't in IE 11.

IE throws an error saying `TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method` on a property assignment in angular 1.3.5. Specifically on

```
    xhr.onload = function requestLoaded() { ... }
```

The xhr object is a regular `new window.XMLHttpRequest()`, though I've tried using an ActiveXObject instead to no effect.

I don't even understand why a (seemingly) straightforward property assignment is throwing an error like this. How do I get around this?

EDIT:

Stack trace, if it makes a difference:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
   at Anonymous function ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:9673:7)
   at sendReq ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:9538:9)
   at serverRequest ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:9255:9)
   at processQueue ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:13077:11)
   at Anonymous function ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:13093:27)
   at Scope.prototype.$eval ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:14293:9)
   at Scope.prototype.$digest ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:14109:15)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:14397:13)
   at Anonymous function ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/angular-1.3.5.js:22829:17)
   at o.event.dispatch ((PATH-TO-JS-FOLDER)/jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3:5999)
```

Line numbers may differ slightly, but line 9673 here is the line containing `xhr.onload =...`

Comment: check through angular bug tracker and also try different versions of angular. Does seem like strange issue but without more of stack trace hard to help with

Comment: @Valyrion did you ever fine a solution to this? I'm seeing this issue in a different library than query, but otherwise its identical and makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As best practice when using angular its best to use the angular built in ajax method.

**Example :**

```
$http.get('../urlpath').then(function(reponse){

$scope.data = response;

});
```

**This is doing the same thing but is more robust and tuned for performance .**

Hope this helps